# Understanding DDR4 RAM marking

Tags: memory

I'm looking to buy new RAM for my computer I can read marking (model number or whatever its called) on RAM as below

```
1Rx8 PC4-2400T UA2-11 (its 8gb module)
```

When I searched online stores there are some close matching, I have no idea actually if they are compatible or not, for example

```
1Rx8 PC4-2400T RD1-11
1Rx8 PC4-2400T UA2-11
1Rx8 PC4-2400T UB1-11
1Rx8 PC4-2400T EO2-11
```

I'm not sure how complex this scenario is, if someone can explain what does these parameters mean that will greatly help me to understand RAM compatibility, in case I missed some important information I'm attaching picture of RAM.

I want to learn what are these parameters like:

1. First chars **1Rx8** what does it mean
2. Last chars **RD1-11** refers to what

[image: Picture of installed RAM]

Comment: I updated question to clear that I want to learn marking parameters, referred question does not answer to my question.

Comment: RD1-11 likely is a batch number. Likewise, 1Rx8, refers to number of memory cells on the PCB (single sided in this case). You are over thinking memory compatibility. The frequency and memory timings should be the same. The numbers your interested in are neither.

Comment: Thanks, what parameters are showing frequency and timing?

Comment: 2400 is the frequency. The timing is likely the -11 in reference to the (CL, tRCD, tRP) values. It does not appear the label indicates the CAS latency but the product overview website for the part number likely does